# Selenium/PhantomJS Can't Find Javascript in Webjars

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, embedded-jetty, webjars

I am running a simple log in test using PhantomJS 1.9.8 and Selenium 2.42.2. Everything is setup with maven and I am using embedded Jetty 8.1.14.v20131031.

Before starting jetty I also add all the webjars to  `org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext#setExtraClasspath`

My login.jsp is using webjars to reference jquery.

```
<script src="webjars/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js"></script>
```

When I run my test I get the following error:

```
Session [81d93a00-9101-11e5-bc34-79a9cbd8ffe4] - page.onError - msg: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
```

If I change the login.jsp to the full URL the test passes.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Is it PhantomJS that is having a problem reading from the webjars or is it Jetty not serving them?

Answer (score 1):

The key was to iterate over the webjars and add each as a classpath resource.

```
//Ensure that webjars are visible as they are packaged in META-INF/resources
ResourcePatternResolver patternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
Resource[] webjarResources = patternResolver.getResources("classpath*:/META-INF/resources");
String[] resources = new String[webjarResources.length + 1];
for(int i = 0; i < webjarResources.length; i++) {
  Resource webjarResource = webjarResources[i];
  resources[i] = webjarResource.getURI().toString();
}

//Try to find the webapp source regardless of the current working directory
URL resource = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("app.properties");
String resourcePath = resource.getPath();
String root = resourcePath.substring(0, resourcePath.lastIndexOf("myapp"));
String path = root + "myapp/src/main/webapp";
File webAppDir = new File(path);

resources[resources.length - 1] = webAppDir.getAbsolutePath();
webapp.setBaseResource(new ResourceCollection(resources));
```